# Duplicate Classes in Cocoa-Touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In a Cocoa-Touch iPhone app, I get this error if I add a class named `List` to my Xcode project:

> objc[25878]: Class List is implemented
>   in both /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib and
>   /Users/steve/Library/Application
>   Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/User/Applications/4883BE28-51DA-493C-9D8A-28FD026708F4/Duplicate Classes Test.app/Duplicate Classes
>   Test. One of the two will be used.
>   Which one is undefined.

I haven't even used the `List` class yet—I've just added it to the project.

The error disappears if the class is renamed. Any idea what might be causing this error? Does Apple have its own `List` class somewhere?

Comment: Because ObjectiveC doesn't support namespaces, it's generally a good idea to prefix your classnames with something. Apple often uses NS and UI (and others), I use my initials.. Were I writing a list class I would call mine JBList. It helps avoid errors like this, especially if Apple ever decides to add similar classes in the future.

Comment: @jbrennan: I am aware of the prefix convention in Objective-C; however, I thought you only needed to prefix classes if you were going to share them (i.e. they would be used outside your own projects)... After this experience, however, I'll probably get in the habit of prefixing all of my classes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that it is the case that Apple has its own List class:

```
reykjavik:/Users/nall% nm  /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib | grep List
00015571 t +[List initialize]
0001552c t +[List newCount:]
000154fc t +[List new]
0001544f t -[List addObject:]
000153f8 t -[List addObjectIfAbsent:]
00015255 t -[List appendList:]
0001510a t -[List capacity]
000155f6 t -[List copyFromZone:]
00015115 t -[List count]
000151bc t -[List empty]
00015485 t -[List freeObjects]
000155aa t -[List free]
...
```

Answer (score 5):

List is one of the classes that goes back to the origins of Objective-C. It's a subclass of Object.  We don't use it anymore, but it's still there so that legacy code doesn't break.